# Delivery issues with Rails + Gmail SMTP in Dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, gmail, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I just released a Rails app in **Dreamhost** and I'm using **Google Apps** for my domain to handle Emai. I created the **admin@domain.com** account to serve as the sender authentication.

I installed [smtp-tls](http://github.com/ambethia/smtp-tls) plugin and my smtp conf is:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :address        => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port           => 587,
  :domain         => "www.domain.com",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :user_name      => "admin@domain.com",
  :password       => 'secret'
}
```

The problem: *Emails sometimes arrives, and sometimes don't*. The recipient addresses are not exclusively Yahoo or GMail accounts, so I think it's not a spam issue. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I just found this in the plugin repo: "If you’re using Ruby on Rails >= 2.2 and Ruby v1.8.7 or greater, you don't need this. Just set enable_starttls_auto in your ActionMailer config". But anyway, sending mail works randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want better tracking of whether or not your emails are getting where you're trying to send them, checkout PostageApp:

http://postageapp.com/

Comment: Hey that looks great! I'll read more about it. Great resource buddy.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that PstageApp doesn't support using GMail SMTP and Google Apps for your domain.

Comment: http://help.postageapp.com/discussions/questions/12-gmail-smtp-and-google-apps-for-your-domain